# Get the TypeSymbol for ain inferred variable in VB with Roslyn

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

Using Roslyn in VB, I'm trying to access the ITypeSymbol for a variable declared using type inference, but am struggling to return the right node. I want the ITypeSymbol to be able to identify if a variable is a reference type or not. In comparison, this is relatively easy in C#. In that case, we can simply take the `node.Declaration.Type` but that's not available off of the VB Declarator.

In the following example, I'm able to access the TypeSymbol from the `AsClause` for the `b` declaration, but that is null for an inferred type used in the `a` variable:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim code = "
Class C
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim a = """"
        Dim b As String = """"
    End Sub
End Class"

    Dim tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(code)
    Dim compilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create("test", {tree}, {MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(GetType(Object).Assembly)})

    Dim result = compilation.Emit(New MemoryStream)

    Dim semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree)

    Dim localNodes = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes.OfType(Of LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)
    For Each node In localNodes
        Dim localSym = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(node.Declarators.Single.Names.Single)
        Trace.WriteLine(localSym.ToDisplayString())

        ' TODO: Figure how to get the typeinfo from inferred type
        Dim symbol = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node) ' Is Nothing
        Dim variableType = node.Declarators.First.AsClause?.Type ' This is null for inferred types
        If variableType IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim typeSymbol = SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(variableType).ConvertedType
            If typeSymbol.IsReferenceType AndAlso typeSymbol.SpecialType <> SpecialType.System_String Then
                ' Real processing goes here

            End If
        End If


    Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the type of the local from `localSym` above:

```
DirectCast(localSym, ILocalSymbol).Type
```

It's unfortunate that that overload of `GetDeclaredSymbol()`'s return type can't be more strongly typed, but unfortunately with a `ModifiedIdentifierSyntax` there isn't a way to know if is from a local, field, etc.

Comment: Thanks. It's odd that this `Type` isn't the same type as the `AsClause.Type` but rather the `semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(variable.AsClause.Type).ConvertedType`. It finally got me over that hump. There's soooo much to learn in Roslyn.